# I'm learning CSS, I can not understand this element selector

Tags: css, html-table

In an example I found the following CSS element:

```
#calendar table{
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I tested it with this table :  `<table id="calendar">`

If i use only `table` or `#calendar` as selector, the style  is applied the same way to the table. If i use them both, it seems that the property are ignored. From my understanding this selector should apply the style to table with the calendar id.

What was the original author intent? Why is it not working? Why does the original author combined a tag type with an ID as id are unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#calendar table` should be applied to table inside a container of id "calendar": `<div id=calendar><table></table></div>`

`table#calendar` should be applied to a table with an id of "calendar": `<table id=calendar></table>`

`#calendar, table` should be applied to either a table or a container with an id of "calendar": `<table></table>` or `<div id=calendar></div>`

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because this selector (`#calendar table`) means you want apply style to a table inside the table with `#calendar` as id.

You try to apply css style to this element `<table id=calendar><table></table></table>` and I presume it doesn't exist.

Comment: There's nothing that indicates that `#calendar` must refer to a table with id calendar. It could be a div with id calendar, an `<li>`, etc. (Now, if the selector was `table#calendar table`, on the other hand, you'd be right.)